# Cancelling azure resource manager deployment

Tags: azure, azure-deployment, azure-resource-manager

Recently I've started creating a new resource group but it seems to be stuck at provisioning server farm resource.
Restarting deployment outputs the following error:

`New-AzureResourceGroup : DeploymentActive: Unable to edit or replace deployment 'App': previous deployment from '8/26/2015 8:48:55 AM' is still active (expiration time is '9/2/2015 8:48:54 AM').`

I have no time to wait for its expiration. Is there a way to cancel Azure ARM deployment?

Comment: Faced the same problem... 7 days expiration?!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Stop-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` should cancel the deployment and preserve the resourcegroup if you need to go that route.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/stop-azurermresourcegroupdeployment

Comment: installing the AzureRM modules can be challenging... BTW: it seems the cmdlet has been renamed with an additional "RM" inside: Stop-AzureRMResourceGroupDeployment

Comment: There will be two versions of the cmdlets for a while - 0.9.8 will have the two modes and AzureRM will simply be Azure.

Comment: [let's try again] - There is a new [preview] version of the cmdlets, one with AzureRM in the name (the 1.0 preview https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azps-1-0-pre/) and that is currently using PowerShellGet for installation, so a bit different than previous versions.  The non-preview version of the cmdlets out now can be installs from the Web Platform Installer.  Both should be in the Web Platform Installer once they are GA.  Both will work against Azure for the foreseeable future.

Comment: thx. this was indeed a bit confusing. also there are many tasks you don't know where to start: old Portal, new Portal, Powershell, azure support...

Answer (score 2):

For those using Azure CLI:

```
> az deployment sub cancel --name <deployment name>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Microsoft is retiring the AzureRm module, the new command looks like this:

```
Stop-AzDeployment
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/stop-azdeployment?view=azps-9.1.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Remove-AzureResourceGroup` cmdlet. It will start deleting the resources and cancel the deployment. However, the best way to avoid waiting for anything is to deploy with a different name, and let the delete run in the background.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn654585.aspx