# I'm having issues with DevOps production deployment - Unable to edit or replace deployment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

Up until yesterday morning I was able to deploy data factory v2 changes in my release pipeline. Then last night during deployment I received an error that the connection was forced closed. Now when I try to deploy to the production environment, I get this error: "Unable to edit or replace deployment 'ArmTemplate_18': previous deployment from '12/10/2019 10:19:27 PM' is still active (expiration time is '12/17/2019 10:19:23 PM')". Am I supposed to wait a week for this error to clear itself?

Answer (score 3):

This message indicates that there’s another deployment going on, with the same name, in the same ARM Resource Group. In order to perform your new deployment, you’ll need to either:

- Wait for the existing deployment to complete
- Stop the in-progress / active deployment

You can stop an active deployment by using the **[Stop-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/stop-azurermresourcegroupdeployment?view=azurermps-6.13.0)** PowerShell command or the azure group deployment stop command in the xPlat CLI tool. Please refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32222691/cancelling-azure-resource-manager-deployment).

Or you can open target Resource Group on the azure portal, go to Deployment tab, find not completed deployments, cancel it, start new deploy. You can refer to this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-mesh-preview/issues/257) for details.

In addition, there is a recently [event](https://status.dev.azure.com/_history) of availability degradation of Azure DevOps .This could also have an impact. Now the engineers have mitigated this event.